# When used Hardcoded value only XML parser is working

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

This is my program, 
I am using STAX Parser to parse an XML document .
When I use hardcoded value then only its working (item.account = "sss";)
But when ever if I try to use
item.account = eventReader.getElementText();
The size of the List is 0 
(List items = new ArrayList();)

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class Pavan {
    static final String DATE        = "date";
    static final String ITEM        = "item";
    static final String MODE        = "mode";
    static final String UNIT        = "unit";
    static final String CURRENT     = "current";
    static final String INTERACTIVE = "interactive";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Position> items = new ArrayList<Position>();
        try {
            String documentAsString = "<request>\r\n" + "<accountid>1234</accountid>\r\n" + "<accountid>234</accountid>\r\n" + "</request>";

            StringReader stringReadertext = new StringReader(documentAsString);
            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stringReadertext);

            XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(reader);
            Position item = null;

            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                    if (startElement.getName().toString().equals("accountid")) {

                        item = new Position();

                        item.account = "sss";
                        //item.account = eventReader.getElementText();
                    }

                }
                // If we reach the end of an item element we add it to the list
                if (event.isEndElement()) {
                    EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                        if (endElement.getName().toString().equals("accountid")) {
                        items.add(item);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(items.size());
    }

}


class Position
{
String account ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your end event was "eaten" and the if (event.isEndElement()) was never triggered. However, when you hardcode, "if (event.isEndElement())" is triggered because the missing of "eventReader.getElementText()".

Comment: Thank you very much PeterPeiGuo , why the event.isEndElement() is not being called properly ?? if                   (event.isEndElement()) {
EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
System.out.println(endElement.getName().getLocalPart()); 
} This is being called and its printing request only , but not accountid , why so ??

Comment: because i posted only a sample xml , like that i need to capture number of tags and then add it to the List .

Answer (score 1):

i believe that `getElementText()` is consuming the end event, so your second if block is never entered.  the docs for that method are a little confusing.